# Importing specific data columns from excel and displaying in Reach Application

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and need help with one of the problem. My requirement is to get specific columns data from an excel sheet and display it on the browser. For that, I am using the react-excel-renderer library. The library is [here](https://github.com/ashishd751/react-excel-renderer)

I have installed the library.

[image: I have installed the library]

And here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {OutTable, ExcelRenderer} from 'react-excel-renderer';

class ConvertToJson extends Component {

fileHandler = (event) => {
    let fileObj = event.target.files[0];

    //just pass the fileObj as parameter
    ExcelRenderer(fileObj, (err, resp) => {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);            
      }
      else{
        this.setState({
          cols: resp.cols,
          rows: resp.rows
        });
      }
    });               

  }

render() {
  return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.fileHandler.bind(this)} style={{"padding":"10px"}} />
    
            <OutTable data={this.state.rows} columns={this.state.cols} tableClassName="ExcelTable2007" tableHeaderRowClass="heading" />

            </div>
    );
    }
}

export default ConvertToJson;
```

I am getting the below error:
[image]

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not initialized `state` in your component. Put this line before `fileHandler` definition.

```
this.state = {
    rows: [],
    cols: []
}
```

Comment: Hi @sirius . Many many thanks. It works for me now. Just a quick question. How can I pick only specific fields from the excel sheet? based on the column headers ?

Comment: If you what you really want is to display specific fields, then you can use custom renderers. https://github.com/nadbm/react-datasheet#custom-renderers

Comment: Thanks Sirius . Really appreciated your help. I will try this custom-renderers.